# Reload react component on clicking a Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I've a scenario where I've to navigate to urls like:

> localhost:3000/students and localhost:3000/students/id

They both render the same component called StudentLookup.

Here are my links and routes:

```
 <Link to="/students" />

 <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/students/:id?" component={StudentLookup} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
 </Switch>
```

Now in my StudentLookup I do:

```
class StudentLookup extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { studentId: ''}
    this.handleSubmitButton = this.handleSubmitButton.bind(this)
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this)
  }

 handleSearch (e) {
    const { studentId } = this.state
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.history.push(`/students/${studentId}`)
    this.props.fetchDetailsForStudent(studentId)
  }

  onInputChange (e) {
    this.setState({ studentId: e.target.value })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const studentId = this.props.match.params.id
    if(id) {
      this.setState({studentId})
      this.props.fetchDetailsForStudent(studentId)
    }
    else if(studentId === "") {
      this.props.history.push('/');
      this.setState({studentId: ''})
    }
    else
      this.setState({ studentId: '' })
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){ 
    console.log(nextProps.params) // this is always undefined
    console.log(this.props.params) // this is always undefined
  }

  render () {
    const studentId = this.props.studentDetails.student_id
    return (
      <div className="search-container">
        <form noValidate="noValidate" onSubmit={this.handleSearch}>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.studentId} onChange={this.onInputChange} placeholder="Enter Student Id" />
          <button type="Submit">Search</button>
          {studentHeader} // we populate this based on id
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    studentDetails: state.studentInfo,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  fetchDetailsForStudent (studentId) {
    dispatch(fetchDetailsForStudent(studentId))
  }
})

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StudentLookup))
```

When I click on localhost:3000/students it shows the empty Search box as expected - then when I enter an id (in search box or url say 123) and hit enter - the studentInfo populates as expected (changing id in the url or search box also works) - however, if I then click back again on localhost:3000/students, it still shows the data from localhost:3000/students/123. 
I'm looking for a way to reload localhost:3000/students again (with just the search box and no studentHeader) when I click the localhost:3000/students link.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Code snippet please...

Comment: you need to have a logic handling where you are on the route. if students render whatever, else if stundents/:id render student. simple logic.

Comment: @ReiDien don't get it (sorry, new to React) - can you point me to an example like where to write this logic?

Answer (score 0):

Use componentWillUpdate or componentWillRecieveProps or componentDidUpdate to check whether the particular param is there in the path or not. If it is not there, set the studentId in the state as empty.

The code will go something like this.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
  {
    if(!nextProps.match.params.id)
       this.setState({studentId : ''})
  }
```

Comment: See my code snippet - I tried this - for some reason the nextProps.params is coming to be undefined.

Comment: well try adding this route to the router.
<Route path="/students" component={StudentLookup} />
and check whether the params in not undefined.

Comment: `<Route path="/students/:id?" component={StudentLookup} />` <-- I've already got this - still need to add the one you suggested?